# Safari css bug with max-height?

Tags: css, safari

I am creating a popup for a registration form, I have set up the css rules for that form and checked on different browsers and only Safari is adding an extra white space between elements.

The size of the forms is:

```
max-height: 90em
```

This is how it looks like on different browsers:

[**Chrome & Firefox**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAxpq.png)

[**Safari**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyckW.png)

Obviously I am missing something. Ideas?

Comment: Why is the first name missing in the safari picture? what do you mean with whitespace, do you mean paddings or margins? Please post your css code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question just in case someone is having the same issue.

This was a Gravity Forms issue. It got fix by adding the following CSS rule:

```
.gf_browser_safari{
    form {
        height: initial;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you might try:

- Switch the max-height from `90em` to `90rem` so it will be sized against the root html element.

  - If you're testing on Safari on your local machine, make sure there are no font size adjustments specified in your Safari settings.  See [The Effect of Browser Settings on the HTML Element Font Size](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/comprehensive-guide-when-to-use-em-vs-rem--cms-23984)
    Make sure the element you're working with is cleared with the css rule `clear:both;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would love to try, but I have an extra difficulty here. I am assigning the max-height rule with jQuery like: $('.object-class').css('max-height', em(90)); Any idea on how to use rem with jQuery?